# Speed Up Time to read File Names from Folder

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I am using PowerQuery to read file names from a Folder (each file is in a subfolder and there are approx 15k records).

The Folder is on another machine on the network.

It takes over 1 hour to refresh the data, how can I speed this up?

Script:

```
let
    Source = Folder.Files("\\Machine\Folder"),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"Name", "Folder Path"}),
in
    #"Removed Other Columns"
```

Comment: How often does the data change? Can you have a script on the host machine periodically dump it to a flat file?

Comment: Try Table.Buffer

Comment: Perhaps mapping the path on Windows.